# Possible bug in RegionDistance with RegionBoundary?

Tags: regions, distance

Code as simple as it is:

```
targetRegion = RegionUnion[Disk[{0, 0}], Disk[{1.8, 0}]];
edgeDistFn = RegionDistance[RegionBoundary@targetRegion]
pts = RandomPoint[targetRegion, {2, 2}];
pts // edgeDistFn
```

This should give distances of all points to the boundary, but works on neither 12.1.1 nor 12.2, with output like:

> ```
> {{RegionDistance[
>    RegionBoundary[
>     BooleanRegion[#1 || #2 &, {Disk[{0, 0}], 
>       Disk[{1.8, 0}]}]], {-0.4243129646, 0.5777295089}], 
>   RegionDistance[
>    RegionBoundary[
>     BooleanRegion[#1 || #2 &, {Disk[{0, 0}], 
>       Disk[{1.8, 
>         0}]}]], {1.227762454, -0.3983038364}]}, {RegionDistance[
>    RegionBoundary[
>     BooleanRegion[#1 || #2 &, {Disk[{0, 0}], 
>       Disk[{1.8, 0}]}]], {2.160377018, 0.6768344764}], 
>   RegionDistance[
>    RegionBoundary[
>     BooleanRegion[#1 || #2 &, {Disk[{0, 0}], 
>       Disk[{1.8, 0}]}]], {1.547838415, -0.00215747549}]}}
> ```

Is this a bug or an individual issue?

---

Despite @cvgmt's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/238594/69875) (a makeshift, inaccurate, and numerical solution), the reason why we need to discretize the region (in many cases, especially those where $\mathtt{Disk}$s, $\mathtt{Cone}$s, *etc.*, are involved in $\mathtt{RegionUnion}$, $\mathtt{RegionIntersection}$, *etc.*) or most of the functions for region measurement will fail to work is still unclear.

Comment: Don't use the [tag:bugs] tag until other people have already confirmed that what you have is a bug.

Comment: @J.M. Get it. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

**Updated**

We also need `DiscretizeRegion`

```
SeedRandom[1];
targetRegion = 
  RegionUnion[Disk[{0, 0}], Disk[{1.8, 0}]] // DiscretizeRegion;
pts = RandomPoint[targetRegion, {2, 2}];
values = SignedRegionDistance[targetRegion][pts]
Show[targetRegion // Region, 
 Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point /@ pts, 
   MapThread[Circle, {pts, Abs@values}, 2]}]]
```

> `{{-0.599128, -0.208482}, {-0.425123, -0.179378}}`

[image]

**Original**

It is recommended to use `SignedRegionDistance`.

```
SeedRandom[1];
targetRegion = RegionUnion[Disk[{0, 0}], Disk[{1.8, 0}]];
pts = RandomPoint[targetRegion, {2, 2}];
values = SignedRegionDistance[targetRegion][pts]
Show[targetRegion // Region, 
 Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point /@ pts, 
   MapThread[Circle, {pts, Abs@values}, 2]}]]
```

> `{{-0.238752, -1.27}, {-0.471944, -0.548317}}`

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is accurate compared to `RegionDistance[targetRegion // RegionBoundary // DiscretizeRegion][pts]` — though I still wonder why `RegionDistance` hasn't done its job well.

Comment: @SneezeFor16Min  It seems that there are something problem on my code , see the graphis. I think the problem come from the `RegionUnion`

Comment: I see. Strange. Discretizing the boundary as I mentioned above, however, does give correct radii (albeit inaccurate): `{{0.2361000112, 0.4516728083}, {0.4690868471, 0.5453502001}}`